# Cannot convert JSON to object using getObject [java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to [C]

Tags: json, mapping, pojo, rest-assured

I have problems with converting JSON response into object using getObject. JSON response looks like this:

{
"data":
{"id":2,
"name":"fuchsia rose",
"year":2001,
"color":"#C74375",
"pantone_value":"17-2031"}
}

I'm using restAssured 2.9.0 and tried this:

```java
public class User {


    String name;
    String color;
    String pantone_value;
    int year;
    int id;
}


 @Test
    public void testUserSerialisation()  {


      User user = given()
              .when()
              .get("https://reqres.in/api/unknown/2")
              .then()
              .extract()
              .response()
              .getBody()
              .jsonPath()
              .getObject("data", User.class);

}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```java
java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to [C
```

Comment: Fields in class `User` should be `public`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to Map JSON Response with the User Object.

User.java

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.apiautomation.framework.titan.models;

/**
 * @author vamsir
 *
 */
public class User {

    public String name;
    public String color;
    public String pantone_value;
    public int year;
    public int id;

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    /**
     * @return the color
     */
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    /**
     * @param color the color to set
     */
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    /**
     * @return the pantone_value
     */
    public String getPantone_value() {
        return pantone_value;
    }
    /**
     * @param pantone_value the pantone_value to set
     */
    public void setPantone_value(String pantone_value) {
        this.pantone_value = pantone_value;
    }
    /**
     * @return the year
     */
    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    /**
     * @param year the year to set
     */
    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

ResReqClassMapping.java

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.apiautomation.framework.titan.testsuites.samples;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.apiautomation.framework.titan.models.User;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;

/**
 * @author vamsir
 *
 */
public class ResReqClassMapping {

    @Test
    public void testUserSerialisation()  {


      User user = RestAssured.given()
              .when()
              .get("https://reqres.in/api/unknown/2")
              .then()
              .extract()
              .response()
              .getBody()
              .jsonPath()
              .getObject("data", User.class);


      System.out.print(user.getColor());

}


}
```

Response

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
#C74375
PASSED: testUserSerialisation

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```